# than what it means this notation $span\{^gf; \, g\in G\}$?

Tags: notation, representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, haar-measure

Can someone please clarify explicitly what it means to $$span\{^gf; \, g\in G\}$$
where $^gf(h):=f(g.h)$, $G$ is a locally compact group and $f\in L^{1}(G)$ the convolution space of all complex-valued integrable functions on $G$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have a link of where you have seen this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if ${}^g f$ is giving you trouble or $\operatorname{span}$.

You give the formula ${}^gf(h):=f(g.h)$, which means ${}^gf$ is the *translate* of the function $f$ by the group element $g$, sending $h\in G\mapsto f(g.h)$.  (In the case $F=(\mathbb R,+)$, we would have (for example) ${}^g f(x)=1/(1+(x+g)^2)$ if $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$, and so on.)  For a given $f\in L^1(G)$, $$\operatorname{span}\{{}^gf:g\in G\}$$ denotes the smallest subspace of $L^1$ containing all the translates of $f$.

Comment: @ kimchi lover; Then, how can write  a function    $\varphi$ in 
 the subspace $\operatorname{span}\{{}^gf:g\in G\}$ ?

Comment: Finite linear combos: $F = \sum_i a_i {}^{g_i}f$; less abstractly, $F(x)=\sum_i a_i f(g_ix)$.

Comment: thank you for your answer @kimchi lover, just, I would like to know
 why "the closed ideal $J$ generated by a  function $f$ in $L^1(G)$" is written as $J= \overline{ \{g*f: \, g\in L^1(G) \}  }$ and not as $\overline{ \{f \}  }$  or something like that ?

Comment: It's not my field, but I'd suppose $\{f\}$ means the set containing the single function $f$, so its closure is uninteresting.  Possibly $\langle f\rangle$ might stand for the ideal generated by $f$, but the notation for $J$ you give seems maximally explicit.

Comment: ok, it comes from general case. i.e., let $R$ be a ring and $I$ is a left ideal of $R$. Then the ideal $I$ is said to be the left ideal generated by an element $a$ in $R$, means that, $I=Ra=\{ra: \, r\in R\}$